# How can I append elements to an Eigen array or matrix?

Tags: c++, arrays, append, eigen

How append element to Eigen array or matrix?

Using STD vector I can use the push_back function,

```
    vector<int> index;

    int random = 1 + (rand() % 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < random; i++)
         index.push_back(i+i);

    for (int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++)
         cout <<"ind = " <<  index[i] << endl;
```

What is the equivalent to the above code using Eigen lib.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to `push_back`, but there is a `resize` method ([documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a9fd0703bd7bfe89d6dc80e2ce87c312a)). Unfortunately, if a reallocation occurs all the previous values are lost.

This is an unfortunate interface decision and requires some effort to efficiently implement a `push_back` like operation.

The follow code is a poor implementation of such, but shows the basic idea.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

using std::cout, std::endl;

template<class T, class U>
void push_back(T& vec, const U& value) {
    auto tmp = vec;
    vec.resize(vec.size() + 1);
    for (auto i = 0; i < tmp.size(); ++i)
        vec[i] = tmp[i];
    vec[vec.size() - 1] = value;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Eigen::VectorXi vec{{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }};
    cout << vec << endl;
    push_back(vec, 7);
    cout << vec << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Update**

Based on @iskakoff's comment, there is also a `conservativeResize` method that keeps the original data in place. This allows for a more efficient emulation of `push_back`.

```cpp
using std::cout, std::endl;

template<class T, class U>
void push_back(T& vec, const U& value) {
    auto n = vec.size();
    vec.conservativeResize(n + 1);
    vec[n] = value;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Eigen::VectorXi vec{{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }};
    cout << vec << endl;
    push_back(vec, 7);
    cout << vec << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In Eigen `resize()` usually reallocates memory, that could be very slow. It's possible to create a larger vector and use `conservativeResize()` method to first shrink it to a desired size and also to avoid performing often memory reallocations and in addition there wouldn't be a necessity of creating explicit temporary object (that could also be memory consuming, imagine vectors of size 10^6).

Comment: I didn't notice that method. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can append elements to an array or matrix using the `resize()` function.
This data structure have fixed sizes, so you need to allocate the required size in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
    Eigen::Array<int, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> index;

    int random = 1 + (rand() % 5);

    index.resize(random);
    for (int i = 0; i < random; i++)
        index[i] = i + i;

    for (int i = 0; i < index.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "ind = " << index[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is possible to simulate this with a `conservativeResize()` and setting the last element, Eigen Arrays/Matrixes are really not intended for this. You should consider one of these alternatives:

1. Allocate the final size at the beginning and insert elements (if you don't know the exact final size, you can allocate more than necessary at the beginning, and do **one** `conservativeResize()` to the final size at the end).
2. Use a `std::vector<int>` and if you want to view it as an Eigen-type use `Eigen::ArrayXi::Map(vec.data(), vec.size())`